# Asymptotic behavior of integral with Laplace's method

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximate-integration, laplace-method

I am working on the following integral

$\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 dT \sqrt{1-(1-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{xT})^2} e^{-n xT},$

as $n\rightarrow \infty$. The goal is to find the asymptotic behavior of the integral to the leading order of $n$.

Obviously, there is a saddle point at $(x,T)=(0,0)$, which is the main difficulty of this calculation. It seems this is related to the Laplace's method introduced in particular in Chapter VIII of [Wong, R. (2001). Asymptotic approximations of integral]. But when I try to change the variable $y_1=(x+T)/2$,  $y_2=(x-T)/2$,  $y_1=\sqrt{\xi}\cosh{\mu}$,  $y_2=\sqrt{\xi}\cosh{\mu}$. It seems all the higher order terms of $\xi$ in the expansion of $\sqrt{1-(1-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{xT})^2}$ will contribute to the results.

Thanks for the satisfying solutions. I think the question is already addressed. This question is made up by myself with the goal of addressing a more complex problem posted here
[Follow up question about Asymptotic behavior of integral with Laplace's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4469866/follow-up-question-about-asymptotic-behavior-of-integral-with-laplaces-method)
This may need some more efforts and possibly a more general method.

Comment: To do this with Laplace's method, you'll need to do some regrouping to move the peak of the exponential away from $(0,0)$, because the "coefficient" function vanishes there. It may help to start with $(u,v)=(x,xT)$, so that the exponent part only depends on one of the variables.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But it is still not clear what I should do next after this substitution. Can you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elaborating on Maxim's comment. If $v=xT$, then
\begin{align*}
I(n)&=\int_0^1\!\! {\int_0^1 {\mathrm{e}^{ - nxT} \sqrt {1 - (1 - \sqrt x  + \sqrt {xT} )^2 } \,\mathrm{d}T}\, \mathrm{d}x} \\& = \int_0^1\!\! {\int_0^x {\mathrm{e}^{ - nv} \frac{{\sqrt {1 - (1 - \sqrt x  + \sqrt v )^2 } }}{x}\,\mathrm{d}v} \,\mathrm{d}x} \\ & = \int_0^1 {\mathrm{e}^{ - nv} \int_v^1 {\frac{{\sqrt {1 - (1 - \sqrt x  + \sqrt v )^2 } }}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} \,\mathrm{d}v} .
\end{align*}
Now,
\begin{align*}
& \int_v^1 {\frac{{\sqrt {1 - (1 - \sqrt x  + \sqrt v )^2 } }}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} 
\\ & = 2(\sqrt {1 - v}  + (1 + \sqrt v )\arccos (\sqrt v ) - v^{1/4} \sqrt {2 + \sqrt v } \arccos (v + \sqrt v  - 1))
\\ & = (\pi  + 2) - 2\sqrt 2 \pi v^{1/4}  + (\pi  + 2)v^{1/2}  - \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{2}\pi v^{3/4}  + \frac{1}{3}v +  \ldots 
\end{align*}
as $v\to 0^+$. Thus, by [Watson's lemma](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.ii),
$$
I(n) \sim \frac{{\pi  + 2}}{n} - \frac{{\sqrt 2 \pi \Gamma (1/4)}}{{2n^{5/4} }} + \frac{{(\pi  + 2)\sqrt \pi  }}{{2n^{3/2} }} - \frac{{3\sqrt 2 \pi \Gamma (3/4)}}{{8n^{7/4} }} + \frac{1}{{3n^2 }} +  \ldots 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: The idea of changing the order of integration was great, since it lets you only apply Watson's lemma once and so you don't have to be concerned about uniformity in that step. This is much better than what I had in mind when I was thinking about this 2 days ago.

Comment: That's a great answer! But I kind of feel this relies on the fact that we accidentally know the analytical result of $\int_v^1 \sqrt{1-(1-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{v})^2}/x dx$. What if  we want to integrate $I=\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 dy f(x,y)e^{-n xy}$. I made up the question which is a simplified version of the problem I need to solve. If we do the substitution $u=xy$, define $h(u)=\int_{u}^1 dx f(x,u/x)/x$. Then, $I=\int_0^1 du h(u)$. It seems we are not able to expand $f(x,u/x)/x$ in this case. For example, when $f(x,y)=\sin\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$, (which is made up randomly,not sure proper enough).

Comment: @Yunkai To leading order you just need to know $\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-(1-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{v})^2}}{x} dx$. And you actually do need to know that just to write down the leading order term because it is literally in the leading coefficient of the expansion. Still, even if you can't analytically do this integral, this leading order analysis still achieves a significant reduction, as you only need to be able to evaluate $\int_0^1 f(x,u/x)/x dx$ for $u \in (0,u_0),u_0 \gg 1/n$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Ian! I think your solution is a good idea. I agree with what you said. I posted another question which I am originally working on. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4469866/follow-up-question-about-asymptotic-behavior-of-integral-with-laplaces-method
I kind of feel hard to find $h(u)$ in the more complex case. I would appreciate it if you can provide more thoughts on the solution of that.

Comment: Yes, I am satisfied with the answer to this question. And I have tried to accept the solution (just noticed I need to do that).

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote
$$I=\int_0^1dx\int_0^1dy\sqrt{1-(1-\sqrt x+\sqrt x\sqrt y)^2}e^{-nxy}$$
Making the substitution $s=nx$
$$=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_0^ns^{1/4}ds\int_0^1dy\sqrt{1-\sqrt y}\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}+\sqrt\frac{s}{n}\sqrt y }\,\,e^{-sy}$$
Now, let's choose $0<\alpha<1$ and split the interval into two parts: $[0;n^\alpha]$ and $[n^\alpha; n]$. We suppose that $1\ll n^\alpha\ll n$ - a more accurate criterion for $\alpha$ we will define a bit later.
Let's denote
$$I_1=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^ns^{1/4}ds\int_0^1dy\sqrt{1-\sqrt y}\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}+\sqrt\frac{s}{n}\sqrt y }\,\,e^{-sy}$$
Due to the fact that $s\in [n^\alpha; n]\,\, s\gg1$, and the integral with respect to $y$ gives the main contribution near $y=0$ - due to the exponent $e^{-sy}$. Noting also that $\sqrt\frac{s}{n}\leqslant 1$, we are allowed to decompose the big square root into the Taylor's series, and evaluate it term by term.
$$I_1=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^ns^{1/4}ds\int_0^1dy\,\Big(1-\frac{\sqrt y}{2}\Big)\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt\frac{s}{n}\sqrt y}{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}} \bigg)\,e^{-sy}\quad(1)$$
Then we evaluate every term: $I_1=I_1^0+I_1^1+I_1^2$
$$I_1^0=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^ns^{1/4}\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}}\,ds\int_0^1dy\,e^{-sy}=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^ns^{-3/4}\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}}(1-e^{-s})\,ds$$
For the term with the exponent we get the following estimation:
$$\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^ns^{-3/4}\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}}e^{-s}\,ds<\frac{\sqrt 2}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^\infty s^{-3/4}e^{-s}\,ds<\frac{\sqrt 2\,n^{-3\alpha/4}}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^\infty e^{-s}\,ds=\frac{\sqrt 2\,e^{-n^\alpha}}{n^{(5+3\alpha)/4}}$$
The main term in $I_1^0$ gives
$$\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^ns^{-3/4}\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}}\,ds=\frac{4}{n}\int_{n^\frac{\alpha-1}{4}}^1ds\sqrt{2-s^2}=\frac{8}{n}\int_{\arcsin\frac{n^\frac{\alpha-1}{4}}{\sqrt2}}^{\pi/4}\cos^2\phi \,d\phi$$
Because we have chosen $1\ll n^\alpha\ll n\,\Rightarrow\, n^\frac{\alpha-1}{4}\ll1$, and, decomposing $\arcsin$, we get the following estimation:
$$\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^ns^{-3/4}\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}}\,ds\approx\frac{\pi+2}{n}-\frac{4\sqrt 2}{n\,n^\frac{1-\alpha}{4}}$$
Therefore, the integral $I_1^0$ is evaluated as
$$\boxed{\,\,I_1^0=\frac{\pi+2}{n}-\frac{4\sqrt 2}{n\,n^\frac{1-\alpha}{4}}+R_0(n,\alpha);\quad R_0(n,\alpha)< \frac{\sqrt 2\,e^{-n^\alpha}}{n^{(5+3\alpha)/4}}\,\,}\qquad(2)$$
In the same way we get the evaluation of other terms of (1):
$$|I_1^1|=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^ns^{1/4}ds\int_0^1dy\,\frac{\sqrt y}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}}\,e^{-sy}<\frac{\text{Const}}{n\,n^\frac{1+\alpha}{4}}\quad(3)$$
$$|I_1^2|=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\alpha}^ns^{1/4}ds\int_0^1dy\,\frac{\sqrt y}{2}\frac{\sqrt\frac{s}{n}}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}}}\,e^{-sy}<\frac{\text{Const}}{n\sqrt n}\quad(4)$$
In the same fashion we evaluate the integral over the interval $[0;n^\alpha]$
$$I_2=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}}\int_0^{n^\alpha}s^{1/4}ds\int_0^1dy\sqrt{1-\sqrt y}\sqrt{2-\sqrt\frac{s}{n}+\sqrt\frac{s}{n}\sqrt y }\,\,e^{-sy}<\frac{\text{Const}}{n\,n^\frac{1-\alpha}{4}}\quad(5)$$
Gathering the biggest terms together, we get the following evaluation:
$$\boxed{\,\,I=I_1+I_2=\frac{\pi+2}{n}+R_1+R_2;\,\,R_1<\frac{C_1}{n\,n^\frac{1-\alpha}{4}}; \,R_2<\frac{C_2}{n\,n^\frac{1+\alpha}{4}}\,\,}\quad(6)$$
We see that the best accuracy we get when we choose $\alpha\to 0$ (though, we have to bear in mind that we still have the requirement $n^\alpha\gg1$).  At $\alpha=0$ the estimation of the remainder gives $R_{1,2}\sim\frac{\text{Const}}{n\,n^{1/4}}$, what explains a considerable error even at a big $n$.

For example, at $n=1000\,\, I=0.00384236... $, and $\frac{\pi+2}{n}=0.00514159... $

The rough evaluation of $R$ for $n=1000$ gives $\frac{R}{I}\sim\frac{\text{Const}}{n^{1/4}}=0.18\cdot\text{Const}$, what is in agreement with $\frac{\frac{\pi+2}{1000}-I(1000)}{I(1000)}=0.34$

$\text{Addendum}$

$\frac{s}{n}\ll1$ for $s\in[0;n^\alpha]$, so we can drop all such terms in eq. (5)
$$I\sim\frac{\sqrt 2}{n^{5/4}}\int_0^{n^\alpha}s^{1/4}ds\int_0^1\sqrt{1-\sqrt y}\,e^{-sy}dy$$
It would be great to evaluate this integral (so far, I don't know how to approach it). But we can also try the following: use $\beta<\alpha$, and split $[0;n^\alpha]$ into $[0; n^\beta]$ and $[n^\beta;n^\alpha].\, I=I_1+I_2$;
$$I_1=\frac{\sqrt 2}{n^{5/4}}\int_0^{n^\beta}s^{1/4}ds\int_0^1\sqrt{1-\sqrt y}\,e^{-sy}dy<\frac{4\sqrt 2\,n^{\beta/4}}{n^{5/4}}+O(n^{-5/4})$$
$$I_2=\frac{\sqrt 2}{n^{5/4}}\int_{n^\beta}^{n^\alpha}s^{1/4}ds\int_0^1\sqrt{1-\sqrt y}\,e^{-sy}dy\sim\frac{4\sqrt 2\,n^{\alpha/4}}{n^{5/4}}+O(\frac{n^{\beta/4}}{n^{5/4}})$$

Comment: I am convinced this is the correct answer. Thanks for the brilliant solutions. Just let me summarize the main point of the solution. You basically tried to separate the case when $x$ is a small number or is of order $O(1)$. This then allows us to do the Taylor expansion, which makes it possible to evalute the integral analytically. This is a very clever strategy.

Comment: As a follow up question: is that possible to find the subleading order of this integral? It seems that bounding Eq. (5) to be a smaller term than the leading order $O(1/N)$ is the critical point to avoid the difficulty. Is it possible to evaluate Eq. (5) instead of just bounding it?

Comment: Yes, you understand the logic of evaluation correctly. Regarding the second point (eq. (5)) - yes, we probably can - added to the Addendum.

Comment: @Yunkai Regarding the higher order terms, we have $I = \int_0^1 f(v) e^{-n v} dv$ with
$$f(v) = \int_v^1 \frac {\sqrt {1 - (1 - \sqrt u + \sqrt v)^2}} u du = \\
2 (\sqrt {1 - v} + (1 + \sqrt v)  \arccos \sqrt v -
 v^{1/4} \sqrt {2 + \sqrt v} \arccos(v + \sqrt v - 1)),$$
so $\sum_{k \geq 0} [v^{k/4}] f(v) \int_0^\infty v^{k/4} e^{-n v} dv$ is a complete asymptotic series for $I$.

Comment: Thanks, Maxim! What if we need to work on a more general form of integral such that $f(v)$ cannot be directly derived. It seems we cannot expand over $u$ and $v$ easily since they can be comparable order of small values. Is there a way to address it?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments by Ian, make the change of variables $u=xT$, $v=x$, after which your integral takes the form
$$\int_0^1\int_0^v \left(1-(1-\sqrt{v}-\sqrt{u})^2\right)^{1/2}e^{-nu}\frac{1}{v}du\,dv.$$
We Taylor expand the square root term to obtain that the integral equals
$$\int_0^1\int_0^v \left(\left(1-(1-\sqrt{v})^2\right)^{1/2}+O(u)\right)e^{-nu}\frac{1}{v}du\,dv=\int_0^1 \frac{\left(1-(1-\sqrt{v})^2\right)^{1/2}}{n}dv+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$
We compute the value of the integral over $v$ to be $\pi/2-2/3$, giving the following final result for the initial expression:
$$\frac{\pi/2-2/3}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$

Comment: Numerically, for $n=1000\quad\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-(1-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{xt})^2} e^{-1000 xt} dx dt=0.00384236...$, while $\frac{\pi/2-2/3}{1000}=0.000904...\quad$

I got $\frac{\pi+2}{n}+o(1/n);\quad\frac{\pi+2}{1000}=0.00514159...$, what also is not quite satisfactory, because the evaluation of $o(1/n)$ gives $o(1/n)=O(1/n^{1+\alpha})$, where $0<\alpha<1$ and is rather small, what provides slow convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. But I think it is not correct to do the Taylor expansion over $u$. Because $v$ is possibly as small as $u$. When you do the expansion, you implicitly assume $u\ll v$. This should introduce large error in the approximated result.

Comment: Both the coefficient of $1/n$ and the order of magnitude of the error term are incorrect.